# Why wont Java read these lines from a file?

Tags: java

Compile and everything is fine but when I try to run the program and input the file for the output, it says it cant read my file. I have a series of numbers stored individually on seperate lines in a file called "Numbers.txt" and it is supposed to take each one by the line and end up calculating the mean and then write the mean to a file called "Results.txt"

Here is there error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java StatsDemo

This program calculates statisticson a file containing a series of numbers
Enter the file name:  Results.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:39)

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

What I have for code is:

```
File rf = new File("Numbers.txt"); //Create a FileReader object passing it the filename
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(rf); //Create a BufferedReader object passing it the FileReader object.
    //priming read to read the first line of the file
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) //create a loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
    {   
     sum += inputFile.nextDouble(); //convert the line into a double value and add the value to the sum
        count ++; //increment the counter
        inputFile.nextLine(); //read a new line from the file
  }
    inputFile.close(); //close the input file
    mean = sum/count; //store the calculated mean
```

I can post more of the program if necessary. I tried searching but I couldn't find an answer to why it wont read the line.

**Update: I moved on and did a Standard Deviation problem. I get a similar error even though I used the new technique that worked previously.**

Error:

```
This program calculates statisticson a file containing a series of numbers
Enter the file name:  Results.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1115)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1379)
    at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:49)
```

My code:

```
        File rf2 = new File("Numbers.txt"); //reconnect to the FileReader object passing it the filename
    Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(rf2);//reconnect to the BufferedReader object passing it the FileReader object.
    sum = 0; //reinitialize the sum of the numbers
    count = 0; //reinitialize the number of numbers added
    //priming read to read the first line of the file
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) //loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
    {
     difference = inputFile.nextDouble() - mean; //convert the line into a double value and subtract the mean
        sum += Math.pow(difference,2); //add the square of the difference to the sum
        count++; //increment the counter
        if (inputFile.hasNextDouble())
        inputFile.nextLine(); //read a new line from the file
    }
  inputFile.close(); //close the input file
    stdDev = Math.sqrt(sum/count); //store the calculated standard deviation
```

Comment: Wanna show us a snippet of the file?

Comment: @peeskillet The "Numbers.txt"?

Comment: I have a feeling this `inputFile.nextLine();` is the problem. You should just read entire lines and parse them.

Comment: compare these two lines you'll get the problem. 
File rf = new File("Numbers.txt");
 Enter the file name:  Results.txt

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Same error with either file. We're meant to be putting "Results.txt" in as they want us to input a file to output the calculation, but it seems to not be reading lines correctly. Its late and the resolve to the problem is escaping me.

Comment: Updated with a very similar problem. I wanted to keep it here to try and confine the problem to a single topic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if `inputFile` has a next line. It's not guaranteed after your first call to `inputFile.nextDouble()`:

```
while (inputFile.hasNextDouble()){ //hasNextDouble() checks for Double availability
   sum += inputFile.nextDouble();
   count ++;
   if(inputFile.hasNextLine()){    //hasNextLine() checks for next Line availability
       inputFile.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that what the while loop is for? To check before every iteration or is the second if loop necessary?

Comment: Sure it checks for the next line, which is presumably read by nextDouble() but then he calls another nextLine() which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah that kinda makes sense. I just tested that and it worked. I appreciate it. Now onto the hard part, standard deviation haha. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you should probably be using hasNextDouble() in the while loop, as hasNext() only guarantees that there is another token, not necessarily another double. I edited my answer to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the Source

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
```

and the source easily found the internet by searching for `Scanner.java:1585`

```
1578    public String nextLine() {
1579        if (hasNextPattern == linePattern())
1580            return getCachedResult();
1581        clearCaches();
1582
1583        String result = findWithinHorizon(linePattern, 0);
1584        if (result == null)
1585            throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");
1586        MatchResult mr = this.match();
1587        String lineSep = mr.group(1);
1588        if (lineSep != null)
1589            result = result.substring(0, result.length() - lineSep.length());
1590        if (result == null)
1591            throw new NoSuchElementException();
1592        else
1593            return result;
1594    }
```

Clearly shows that there aren't any *lines* in the file that match the *pattern* of what is considered a *line* as far as the `Scanner` is concerned.

#### The problem is one of the following:

- You are either reaching the end of the file because you are calling a `.nextXXX()` method twice inside a single check for `.hasNext()`
- The file(s) don't have proper line ending characters and all the contents are all on a single line.

View the file in a proper text editor *( NOT notepad.exe )* and turn off word wrap and turn on invisibles, or better yet use a hex editor to view the contents of the file.

Comment: In that case would something like `scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` help?

Comment: Checked to make sure word wrap is off. In the Numbers.txt file, it has about 2003 lines of random numbers. Whats the best way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue for the standard deviation is you used the wrong variable, you used inputFile instead of inputFile2